# Question regarding File Handling (writing and reading simultaneously to text file)?

Tags: c, file, text

I'm trying to  write a code where i can replace each character in a text file with 'x' within a single loop.
I'm not able to get the desired output and also giving a ch!==EOF condition causes an infinite loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("text.txt","r+");
    char ch;
    int i=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(i!=5)
        {
            ch=fgetc(fp);
            fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
            fputc('x',fp);
            printf("%c",ch);
            i++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**Expected Output**   : Hello 
**Actual Result**     : Heeee

given the file contains text "Hello"
Using GCC compiler.

Comment: Your code outputs the expected result when compiled with the command `gcc <Your C file>`. Did you add any additional flags when compiling your code?

Comment: @xing Thank you so much. Worked just fine.

Comment: @VietHTran I'm actually using CodeBlocks with a gcc compiler.(Not on Linux)